# Jupyter Notebook will not open on Mac (.zsh)

Tags: jupyter

I know for this issue there are some solutions but they didn't work for me. And I don't understand how I can do. I guess I have to change PATH stuff, but I don't understand to be honest.

My terminal .zsh (I can't change this with .bash, because I have to use it.)
My system Mac OS Catalina

I installed Anaconda. When I try to launch Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda, Jupiter notebook doesn't open on the web browser, it says waiting for localhost.
And when I try to launch Jupyter Notebook in terminal with code 'jupyter notebook'. It says 'zsh: command not found: jupyter'

Please help, this thing drive me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. The reason for this was the Antivirus program. It blocks to open Jupyter Notebook on the web browser. If you have same problem, remove your antivirus program.